# How could you import data from a StackOverflow form into javascript?

Tags: javascript

If you wanted to take a StackOverflow question or answer and get the data (such as upvotes, views, and comments) in a format readable by javascript. This is for uses such as checking data of my questions and answers in a simple extension without going to the website.

Comment: StackExchange comes with an API. https://api.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Thanks, I'm having a look now.